# Query Builder array_agg Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I have a question about Laravel Eloquent ORM, can i use this tool to create **Postgresql** `array_agg`?, I have this query:

[image]

this query returns me:

> [{"id":1, "contact_name":"name", "description":"description", "discharge":0, "latitude":null, "longitude":null, "town":null, "country":null, "province":null,
>   "numbers":"{77777,888888}", "emails":"{email@email.com, email2@email2.com}"}]

And im trying to create this query with eloquent: i have this code:

[image]

This second query returns me all the previous data except the numbers and emails, because i dont have any idea how to put `array_agg` in this query.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why would you want to necessarily use Eloquent in this case? BTW the second version of your code is not Eloquent but rather Query Builder.

Comment: Ops, sorry about that, its because i want to implement a clean code using `Query Builder`, or is good to use all the query inside `DB::select`? @peterm

Comment: And also i want to add the parameter inside `Query Builder where `, looks more understandable @peterm

Comment: In situations like this when you have a sophisticated query I'd recommend to keep it straight SQL which allows you to have a full control, precision and performance.

Comment: Use query placeholders and pass bindings to `DB::select()` as a second parameter to make it cleaner and more importantly leverage prepared statements and protect against sql-injections.

Comment: `$users = DB::select('SELECT ... WHERE i.user_id = ? AND i.user_provider_id = ?', [$user_id, $provider_id]);`

Comment: An alternative would be to do it in Laravel idiomatic way - use Eloquent, define properly relationships and then eager load them as needed. This way you'll have properly hydrated models in the end. But this will be slower than straight SQL because Eloquent will run a separate query for each relationship, which may or may not be an issue in your case.

Comment: Got it, thanks @peterm